# What is the difference between awareness and focus?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between awareness and focus? 
If it matters my impetus is meditation lingo.

Comment: I'm driving along on a highway.  I am aware of the truck behind me, but I am focused on the intersection ahead.

Comment: Can your focus be both the intersection and the truck? ... and your running late ... and the gas is low?

Comment: Yeah, and while your at it, check your Facebook status on you phone.

Answer (score 1):

[Awareness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awareness)

The quality or state of being aware : knowledge and understanding that something is happening or exists.

[Focus](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/focus)

To direct your attention or effort at something specific.

Just because you are **aware**, doesn't mean you are **focused**.

Though, in the context you have put, you could say that focus is limited to concentrate yourself in one subject, one thing. While awareness is the perception of the surroundings.

Comment: (Why isn’t ‘the surroundings’ one thing?   How is being focused on the surroundings different than being aware of the surroundings?)

Comment: You cannot be focused on the surroundings. Imagine something like that: The TV and the radio are turned on, while your loved one is cooking. You are aware that all these three things are happening, right? You are able to detect they all. But, can you pay attention to all of them at same time? Can you focus in all three at the same time? If you're a superhuman maybe heh. Of course the situation may depends, I just gave a rather simplistic example. Can the surroundings be only one thing? That's up to your judgment but I hard believe, since often more than one thing is happening at same time.

Comment: Yes, exactly ... why can't the surroundings be one thing. (Can a baseball batter be focused on the surroundings?)

Comment: Why would the surroundings be one thing? Definition: the things and conditions around a person or thing.
"I took up the time admiring my surroundings". By things and conditions, it implies that more than one thing is happening at same time, so it cannot be only one thing.

Comment: Ok, so is it "The baseball batter was focused on the field." or  "The baseball batter was focused on all the players on the field."? 

Isn't a group always a single group? "A" group.